# How to fix an issue with SQL server query that contains a conditional case to use 'group by' when using the field

Tags: sql, sql-server

****SAMPLE QUERY REVISED FOR SIMPLICITY*

I'm running a conditional query in SQL Server and having this issue when wrapping this specific CASE condition within the GROUP BY query.
I simulate the query to one that can be simplified and I appreciate your help on this:

```
DECLARE @orders_table TABLE(
i_date DATE,
customer_id INT,
customer_score INT,
orders INT
);

INSERT @orders_table
VALUES
('2022-11-28', 100, 3, 1),
('2022-11-28', 101, 7, 4),
('2022-11-29', 102, 6, 1),
('2022-11-30', 103, 1, 5)

DECLARE @group_by_customer_id BIT = 1;
SELECT
i_date,
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN customer_id ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN CASE WHEN customer_score > 5 THEN customer_score ELSE 0 END ELSE NULL END,
SUM(orders)
FROM
@orders_table
GROUP BY
i_date,
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN customer_id ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN customer_score ELSE NULL END;
```

The 'aggregate' issue is thrown as I'm using the condition of "WHEN customer_score > 5" within the query. I just need to figure out how to achieve the result of using each line just according to the case when @group_by_customer_id for e.g.

```
Column '@orders_table.customer_score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Column '@orders_table.customer_score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The 'columns' and the 'group by' are identical according to the case.
The problematic line is this one:

```
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN CASE WHEN customer_score > 5 THEN customer_score ELSE 0 END ELSE NULL END,
```

And it works perfectly if I remove the nested CASE:

```
CASE WHEN @group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN customer_score ELSE NULL END,
```

The result I'm trying to achieve is:

[image]

[image]

I do NOT want to switch to dynamic SQL...
Thanks

Comment: For conditional aggregates, the aggregate should be around the *entire* expression, not the (one of the ) returned expression(s).

Comment: @Larnu - thanks. Not sure I understand when you mean "the entire expression" as all works perfect if I'm not using that nested "CASE WHEN customer_score > 5 THEN..."

Also this line:
THEN customer_score * SUM(orders)
should have been:
THEN SUM(customer_score * orders)
but still it's irrelevant as we can delete this line.

Comment: `SUM(CASE...END)` not `CASE WHEN... THEN SUM(...) END`

Comment: But that's not the purpose of the query, as I don't want to make the SUM (or anything else) if the CASE condition isn't met.

Wrapping the SUM at the beginning will SUM something anyways.

Comment: The `SUM` of `NULL` is `NULL`; why is that an issue over "return `NULL` if not the value I want"? They both return `NULL`.

Comment: That's right, but I mean that the issue is NOT with the line of SUM - the key may be here:
when using:

CASE WHEN @ group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN CASE WHEN customer_score > 5 THEN customer_score ELSE 0 END ELSE NULL END AS customer_score, 

It gives the error about 'customer_score'.
However, when doing it like this:

CASE WHEN @ group_by_customer_id = 1 THEN customer_score ELSE NULL END AS customer_score,

It works perfect

Comment: Your expression in the group by isn't the same expression as in the select - therefore the columns used in the part of the expression that is not also included in the group by must be included in an aggregate function.  So either include the full case expression as the grouping - or modify the case expression to be inside the SUM.  You may also need to include the expression as a column - at least I would so the actual customer score is included in the results.